# Set new Guid id in Repository method

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern

I'm trying to implement generic repository pattern and I have a small problem with my "Add" method:

```
  public class GenericRepository<T> where T : class
  {
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public async Task AddAsync(T t)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(t);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
   }
```

This method works, but since "Id" property of my entity is Guid I get all zeros as Id.

So in my method I should set new Guid as Id:

```
t.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

but I'm not sure how can I set Id property of my entity via generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have all entities implement an interface and add this interface as a constraint on `T`.

For example:

```
public interface IEntity
{
  Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity : IEntity
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class GenericRepository<T> where T class, IEntity
{
  public async Task AddAsync (T t)
  {
    ...
    T.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a "generic repository pattern" is a red flag in my mind. Repository patterns usually contain very specific methods, such as `GetTopTenContributingUsers` or `AddNewUser`, to prevent leaky abstractions back to the caller and to abstract the data layer away. DbContext is a pretty generic pattern already so trying to wrap another generic abstraction around it seems a little misguided on the face of it.

You can't *set* a property using generics, but as [@MotoSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068074/) said you could add one to your each of you entities using a common interface. Bear in mind though that if your table is insert heavy then using a Guid as a primary key in the database table is generally discouraged as they do not index well and will have a negative performance impact over time.